# Is there type system with subtype relation that support exclusive struct field?

Tags: typescript, types, polymorphism, purescript, entity-component-system

TLDR:
Is there a type system which allows we to express a type (constraint/interface) `I = NoField<'a'>`, such that for all type `T`, if `T <: I`, then `T` is a struct and does not have a specific field `a`?

---

Detail version:
In TypeScript, we have `&`, `|` type constructors, and have subtype rules (structural polymorphsim) like:
for all type `A`, `B`, we have `A extends A | B` and `A & B extends A`.

There is type utility `Exclude`, we can define type `I` similar to what `NoField` described above, but the `extends` semantic is different. The `NoField` semantic is more close to [`io-ts`'s exact type](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/blob/master/index.md#exact-types), except that `io-ts`'s `excat` type does really work on type level.

It seems that `row polymorphism` do support some notation `r/l` to express a row without filed `l`, but I don't understand it yet. And in language like PureScript, its row constraint seems not support the exclude notation. Is `row polymorphism` a type system? Can it express the `NoField` semantic described above?

Motivation: When learning Unity's ECS system, its query seems like a limited version of structural polymorphism on archetypes, and `WithAll` is related to `&` in typescript, `WithAny` is related to `|` in typescript, but for `WithNone` constructor, I can not find a corresponding type level notation/semantic.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need, but there is [Lacks](https://pursuit.purescript.org/builtins/docs/Prim.Row#t:Lacks): `takeRowWithoutA :: Lacks "a" r => { | r } -> Unit`

Comment: Yes, it is what I'm looking for. And by the way, the `takeRowWithoutA` example helps a lot, actually I'm can't use PureScript fluently yet, and after reading `Lacks` doc I didn't get the idea, but the example provides exactly the missing piece.

Comment: This package has some interesting examples https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-record/3.0.0/docs/Record
Happy I could help!